# Windows application and SQL Server 2000 database on client machine

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, sql-server-2000

I have installed a .net Windows application on a client's machine and its database is in SQL Server 2000.

For the application, I installed the .net framework and other support software and for database I installed SQL Server 2000 and created a database over there and connect it. Working properly

But now client changed from Windows XP to Windows 7. I search for installation of SQL Server 2000, but it's not working over there. So what I did, I sent the `.mdf` file of the database with exe application and make connection string

```
<add name="AccountingConnectionString" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\SetupOfApplication\DataBase\Database.mdf;User Instance=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and it's also working.

Now i change something in database, and trying to update the `.mdf` file but its not reflecting the new one `.mdf` is getting the old one. I am stuck......

Did I do something wrong? Because its difficult for me to fix.

OR

I want to know what is the efficient way of use of SQL Server 2000 database on Windows 7 or any else solution is there?

Comment: Connection string is : "<add name="AccountingConnectionString" 
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
    AttachDBFilename=C:\SetupOfApplication\DataBase\AccountManager.mdf;
    User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Why not use a version of SQL Server that is less than a decade old?

Comment: What does "trying to update" mean? How are you trying to update? Are you doing it properly (disconnecting from the database first, replacing the database file, and reconnecting)?

Comment: Why don't you try to move your database to a new version of sql server?